# argument is null or empty - start-job

Tags: azure, powershell

I am getting an argument is null error while trying to execute below command. Is there a way to can call the variable inside start-job

```
$RG = "xx"
$Location1 = "xx"
$VNET1="xx"
$PublicIP1="xx"
$VNGW1 = "xx"

    Start-Job {
New-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -Name $VNGW1  -ResourceGroupName $RG -Location $Location1 -GatewayType Vpn -VpnType RouteBased -GatewaySku VpnGw1 -Asn 65511  -IpConfigurations $gwipconf1 -EnableBgp $True
}
```

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and explain _why_ the resources should be created at the same time. Most of the cloud operatios are async anyway. That being said, having two `New-AzResourceGroup` cmdlets on the same line separated by a colon does not make those parallel but sequental calls.

Comment: Hi vonPryz, I am trying to reduce the run time of the script . For example, i need two virtual network gateways in different sites and each resource takes approx 30 mins to complete. So if i can create both VNGW in different locations at same time, i think i can reduce the script running time

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, so you should edit the question instead. Anyway, the [actual question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) is that you have performance issues about how to create Azure resources. Why not ask something like "Creating new resource group takes 30 minutes. Is there a way to speed it up?"

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or
> empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the
> command again.

Without the Argument list in Start-Job cmdlet, we cannot use the variables.

We have created a PowerShell script & tested the below scripts in our environment which is working fine. We can create Virtual Network Gateway using start-job in below two ways:

1. Using Variables as Argument List
2. Using Script in Start-Job

**Using Variables as Argument List:**

- Firstly, We have created all the dependency resources for Virtual Network Gateway using below cmdlets:

```
    $subnet = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name 'gatewaysubnet' -AddressPrefix '10.254.0.0/27'
    $ngwpip = New-AzPublicIpAddress -Name ngwpip -ResourceGroupName "vnet-gateway" -Location "UK West" -AllocationMethod Dynamic
    $vnet = New-AzVirtualNetwork -AddressPrefix "10.254.0.0/27" -Location "UK West" -Name vnet-gateway -ResourceGroupName "vnet-gateway" -Subnet $subnet
    $subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -name 'gatewaysubnet' -VirtualNetwork $vnet
    $ngwipconfig = New-AzVirtualNetworkGatewayIpConfig -Name ngwipconfig -SubnetId $subnet.Id -PublicIpAddressId $ngwpip.Id
```

- Once the dependencies are created, we used the below Start-Job cmdlet for the  creation of  Virtual Network Gateway:

```
  $RG = "xx"
  $Location = "xx"
  $gwipconf = "xx"
  $VNGW = "xx"
    
     Start-Job {
    New-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -Name $args[3]  -ResourceGroupName $args[0] -Location $ args[1]  -GatewayType Vpn -VpnType RouteBased -GatewaySku VpnGw1 -Asn 65511  -IpConfigurations $ args[2]  -EnableBgp $True
    } -ArgumentList @($RG, $Location, $gwipconf, $VNGW)
```

**Using Script in Start-Job:**

- Here, we have created a PowerShell file (gateway.ps1) & stored in local machine which contains the dependent resources creation followed by virtual network gateway creation(using the start-job).

```
New-AzResourceGroup -Location "UK West" -Name "vnet-gateway"
$subnet = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name 'gatewaysubnet' -AddressPrefix '10.254.0.0/27'

$ngwpip = New-AzPublicIpAddress -Name ngwpip -ResourceGroupName "vnet-gateway" -Location "UK West" -AllocationMethod Dynamic
$vnet = New-AzVirtualNetwork -AddressPrefix "10.254.0.0/27" -Location "UK West" -Name vnet-gateway -ResourceGroupName "vnet-gateway" -Subnet $subnet
$subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -name 'gatewaysubnet' -VirtualNetwork $vnet
$ngwipconfig = New-AzVirtualNetworkGatewayIpConfig -Name ngwipconfig -SubnetId $subnet.Id -PublicIpAddressId $ngwpip.Id

New-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -Name myNGW -ResourceGroupName vnet-gateway -Location "UK West" -IpConfigurations $ngwIpConfig  -GatewayType "Vpn" -VpnType "RouteBased" -GatewaySku "Basic" -CustomRoute 192.168.0.0/24
```

- Now, We have passed the above powershell script file path as an argument to the Start-job to create VPN gateway:

```
start-job -filepath \<pathofPowershellScript>
```

Here is the sample output for the reference :

[image]